# Another nginx ingress rewrite-target problem

Tags: node.js, nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have one service and a single ingress resource with kubenetes nginx ingress controller. I want the `/student` path of my url to go to the root of the application and match any other url segments which follow the `student`.

For example: http://example.com/student/ver should match the `/ver` route of my application.

However, my ingress always hit the application with the `/student` url path prefixing the other url segments. If I call http://example.com/student/ver, my application is hit with the same url (`student/ver`).

My ingress:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
  name: ingress-resource
spec:
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: lesson-streaming
          servicePort: 80
        path: /student
```

I spent days with this and was not successful once.

---

Edit:

The ingress is changed to the following - not my requests say `http 404`

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
  name: ingress-resource
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: lesson-streaming
          servicePort: 80
        path: /student(/|$)(.*)
```

Comment: The official example is exactly what you need https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/master/docs/examples/rewrite#examples.

Comment: @Charlie Have you managed to make it work?

Comment: @kitt Sorry - it didn't work

Comment: @Charlie Your annotation key is incorrect, which should be `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target`

Comment: @kitt Works very well. Please provide this as an answer. I will accept.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can follow the [link](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/master/docs/examples/rewrite#examples) to use the `rewrite-target` annotation correctly and keep the right key `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target`.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
  name: rewrite
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - host: rewrite.bar.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: http-svc
          servicePort: 80
        path: /something(/|$)(.*)
```

Comment: this doesn't work in networking.k8s.io/v1

Answer (score 4):

I have tried many times to execute properly path based routing in nginx ingress controller but I have found the main reason behind the path based routing not working.

replace the `(nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /)` to `(nginx.org/rewrites: "serviceName=servicename rewrite=/")`

must add `ingressClassName` in `spec`

in my case
I have kubernetes 1.23.0 & nginx/1.21.6

I hope this will resolve the above problem.
Best of luck

Answer (score 2):

Im using k8 - v1.25.2 along with nginx-Ingress v2.4.1 https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/installation/installation-with-manifests/

nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2 - doesnt work

instead use :
nginx.org/rewrites: "serviceName=app1-svc rewrite=/;serviceName=app2-svc rewrite=/"

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1 
kind: Ingress 
metadata:
  name: path-ingress
  namespace: default
  annotations:    
    nginx.org/rewrites: "serviceName=app1-svc rewrite=/;serviceName=app2-svc rewrite=/"
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx  
  rules:
  - host: apps.relo.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: app1-svc
            port:
              number: 2041
        path: /app1
        pathType: Prefix
      - backend:
          service:
            name: app2-svc
            port:
              number: 2042
        path: /app2
        pathType: Prefix
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33009138)

Comment: May be my Google foo, but docs on this seem limited. An example of the above on the NGINX ingress controller git repo: https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/tree/v2.4.1/examples/ingress-resources/rewrites