# Ngnix ingress rewrite-target does not work

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, minikube, nginx-ingress

I did exactly as is it told here: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/master/docs/examples/rewrite#examples

```
$ echo '
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
  name: rewrite
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - host: rewrite.bar.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: coffee-svc
          servicePort: 80
        path: /something(/|$)(.*)
' | kubectl create -f -
```

The ingress is created, I added `rewrite.bar.com` to my `/etc/hosts` to the ip of the minikube.
`coffee-svs` is the service from this example: https://github.com/nginxinc/NGINX-Demos/tree/master/kubernetes-demo-nginx-ingress-resources

Yet there is no rewrite happening, I have exactly the same use case as shown here: [Another nginx ingress rewrite-target problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61185530/another-nginx-ingress-rewrite-target-problem), yet the proposed solution does not work.

When I do `curl rewrite.bar.com/something` there is a `404 Not Found` response.

The expected behavior would be that `rewrite.bar.com/something` is rewritten as `rewrite.bar.com/` and then call coffee-svc on path `/`.

Also doing `curl -I -k rewrite.bar.com/` returns:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: nginx/1.17.9
Date: Sat, 02 May 2020 15:24:02 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 153
Connection: keep-alive
```

I have nginx ingress installed with helm, using `stable/nginx-ingress`, currently version `0.30.0`.

Kubernetes version is `1.14`.

Edit:
Adding ingress-controller-pod logs

```
I0502 15:52:00.344425       7 flags.go:215] Watching for Ingress class: nginx
W0502 15:52:00.344820       7 flags.go:260] SSL certificate chain completion is disabled (--enable-ssl-chain-completion=false)
W0502 15:52:00.344909       7 client_config.go:543] Neither --kubeconfig nor --master was specified.  Using the inClusterConfig.  This might not work.
I0502 15:52:00.345341       7 main.go:193] Creating API client for https://10.96.0.1:443
I0502 15:52:00.355089       7 main.go:237] Running in Kubernetes cluster version v1.14 (v1.14.1) - git (clean) commit b7394102d6ef778017f2ca4046abbaa23b88c290 - platform linux/amd64
I0502 15:52:00.358184       7 main.go:91] Validated default/my-nginx-ingress-default-backend as the default backend.
I0502 15:52:00.836581       7 main.go:102] SSL fake certificate created /etc/ingress-controller/ssl/default-fake-certificate.pem
W0502 15:52:00.873934       7 store.go:628] Unexpected error reading configuration configmap: configmaps "my-nginx-ingress-controller" not found
I0502 15:52:00.911054       7 nginx.go:263] Starting NGINX Ingress controller
I0502 15:52:02.035037       7 event.go:281] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"default", Name:"rewrite", UID:"60b7853f-8c86-11ea-b3ad-080027f64399", APIVersion:"networking.k8s.io/v1beta1", ResourceVersion:"367651", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'CREATE' Ingress default/rewrite
I0502 15:52:02.113846       7 nginx.go:307] Starting NGINX process
I0502 15:52:02.116614       7 leaderelection.go:242] attempting to acquire leader lease  default/ingress-controller-leader-nginx...
I0502 15:52:02.123127       7 controller.go:137] Configuration changes detected, backend reload required.
I0502 15:52:02.135944       7 status.go:86] new leader elected: my-nginx-ingress-controller-6fcc8d7f97-r9d8t
I0502 15:52:02.321762       7 controller.go:153] Backend successfully reloaded.
I0502 15:52:02.321833       7 controller.go:162] Initial sync, sleeping for 1 second.
I0502 15:52:55.451512       7 leaderelection.go:252] successfully acquired lease default/ingress-controller-leader-nginx
I0502 15:52:55.452458       7 status.go:86] new leader elected: my-nginx-ingress-controller-6fcc8d7f97-7p8g6
I0502 15:52:55.470245       7 status.go:274] updating Ingress default/rewrite status from [] to [{10.0.2.15 }]
I0502 15:52:55.475571       7 event.go:281] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"default", Name:"rewrite", UID:"60b7853f-8c86-11ea-b3ad-080027f64399", APIVersion:"networking.k8s.io/v1beta1", ResourceVersion:"367750", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'UPDATE' Ingress default/rewrite
I0502 15:53:18.288519       7 controller.go:137] Configuration changes detected, backend reload required.
I0502 15:53:18.291422       7 event.go:281] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"default", Name:"rewrite", UID:"60b7853f-8c86-11ea-b3ad-080027f64399", APIVersion:"networking.k8s.io/v1beta1", ResourceVersion:"367783", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'DELETE' Ingress default/rewrite
I0502 15:53:18.403753       7 controller.go:153] Backend successfully reloaded.
I0502 15:53:20.187998       7 event.go:281] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"default", Name:"rewrite", UID:"0ba43588-8c8d-11ea-b3ad-080027f64399", APIVersion:"networking.k8s.io/v1beta1", ResourceVersion:"367788", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'CREATE' Ingress default/rewrite
I0502 15:53:21.623215       7 controller.go:137] Configuration changes detected, backend reload required.
I0502 15:53:21.796798       7 controller.go:153] Backend successfully reloaded.
```

Answer (score 1):

Finnally I solved it by removing the entire minikube cluster:

```
minikube delete
minikube start
```

There was somewhere, somehow a configuration affecting the ingress. Then it worked fine. Pitty I couldn't know the culprit config or deployment.

Answer (score 0):

The curl command should be

```
curl rewrite.bar.com/something --header "Host: rewrite.bar.com"
```

The `Host` header is what nginx uses to know which host sent the request and apply the ingress rule for host `rewrite.bar.com` and the rewrite happens as defined in the rule.

If you use a browser to access the same url then this header is automatically sent by the browser.

Use below to test service via curl from another pod

```
kubectl run curl --image=radial/busyboxplus:curl -i --tty

If you don't see a command prompt, try pressing enter.

[ root@curl:/ ]$ curl coffee-svc
```

Comment: But the ingress rewrite is supposed to remove the `something`, that is the whole point of having the rewrite section and `/something

Comment: if you curl the service directly on the same endpoint  from another pod does it return similar response? What the response of rewrite.bar.com/nginx

Comment: `curl rewrite.bar.com/nginx` returns also `404`

Comment: Using curl rewrite.bar.com/something --header "Host: rewrite.bar.com" should work

Comment: No, it still does not work. Also posting `rewrite.bar.com/something` in a browser shows `404` too

Comment: curl the service directly from another pod worked? If that does not work then its an issue with the service or some other issue and not issue with ingress

Comment: share output of kubectl describe svc servicename. If you curl the pod IP directly does it work?

Comment: I give up, the curl from within another pod does not work since curl is not installed, then I try apt-get install and apt-get is not installed. It is all a mess. I most likely will create different ingresses, one per microservice I need to redirect to.

Comment: Did you have to provide the HOST header in curl or it worked without it?